# Is there a way to optimize searching for specific keys in a hash table with multiple keys

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

search hash table with multile keys

i have a hash table with 3 keys: source-address,destination-address and application-id. whenever a packet received will make this tuple and serach in hash table it gives proper entry, it works perfectly. If i want to search only with 1 key or 2 keys like want to get all entries with a application-id number, i have to walk all entries. or i have to make another table with sorted based on each key.

My question is is there any way to enhance the hash table to get entries with multiple keys, like maintaining multile hash's for each bucket or any other option. is there any libraries to make search easy.

code is in c language and we are using fdio vpp for our development.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use an in-memory database or something like sqlite.

4 hash tables.

First table maps an entry id (integer) to an Entry (whatever that is)

```
unordered_map<int, shared_ptr<Entry>> entries;
```

Then three hash tables for mapping the different keys to different collections:

```
 unordered_map<Address, unordered_set<int>> sourceAddressMap;
 unordered_map<Address, unordered_set<int>> destAddressMap;
 unordered_map<AppId,   unordered_set<int>> appIdMap;
```

And maybe a 5th table for searching for an exact packet by all three keys:

```
 unordered_map<Key, unordered_set<int>> entryTable
```

Where "Key" is the thing you are using today to make a key from all three fields.

Inserting is simple and still O(1).  Whenever you get a new packet (Entry), assign it a unique id integer and then insert into all your tables:

```
 shared_ptr<Entry> entry = makeNewEntryFromPacket(packet);
 int id = nextId++;
 sourceAddressMap[entry.sourceAddress].insert(id);
 destAddressMap[entry.destAddres].insert(id);
 appIdMap[entry.appId].insert(id);

 entryTable[makeKey(entry.sourceAddress, entry.destAddress, entry.appId)].insert(id);
```

Looking up all the entries from a single key (e.g. app id). Still O(1).

```
 const auto& lookup = sourceAddressMap[appId];
 for (int id: lookup) {
     auto entry = entries[id];
     // do something interesting with entry...
 }
```

Multi-key lookup (all the entries from a specific source address and app id):

```
const auto& lookup1 = sourceAddressMap[address];
const auto& lookup2 = appIdMap[appId];
std::vector<int> v;
std::set_interection(lookup1.begin, lookup1.end(), lookup2.begin, lookup2.end(), std::back_inserter(v));    


 for (int id : v) {
     auto entry = entries[id];
     // do something interesting with entry...
 }
```

There's also std::set_union if you want an "or" operation on either key.

The challenge from this design is that it feels inherently fragile keeping multiple tables in sync. That's why I suggested a database as a more robust solution if you need to scale.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, clearly you can have distinct tables for your various combinations of key components (source-address, destination-address and/or application-id), but if you want to explore forcing these multiple functions on to a single table, then you could... you'll have to carefully consider the fundamental properties of hash tables: hashing of keys, comparing keys, collision management, and the option of storing some value alongside the key data.  The easiest way to handle the variations in the keys is to see if there's a sentinel value for each key component that can play the part of a wildcard.  For example, if your source and destination addresses and application id are typically positive integers, you could store 0 as a wildcard sentinel.  Or maybe, you could use -1, or the maximum value for the data type.  At worst, you can add 3 bits to the keys to track which components are wildcards.  Then if your hash function and key comparison function is adapted (if even necessary) to cope with the sentinel value or extra bits alongside the valid values.  That's the "front end" side of hashing - it will let you get to the ideal bucket.  But, at/from that bucket (i.e. using open or closed addressing), you might want entries with non-sentinel key components, or one of the sentinel-carrying "wildcard" entries - the tricky thing is they need to be linked to a container of wildcard-matching entries.

In C++, this could be expressed as:

```
struct key {
    optional<SrcAddr> src;
    optional<DstAddr> dst;
    optional<AppId> appid;
};


unordered_map<key, std::list<key>>
```

Of course, you'll need to add a lot of extra entries in the hash table to maintain the extra key linkages and lists.